# Backtracing in ollydbg v2

Tags: backtrace, ollydbg

I use now ollydbg v2 and wanted to know how I can use the backtrace operation. In ollydbg v1, I remember that I need to push the minus ("-") operator, everything was colored gray and I could also see the old register values.

In ollydbg v2 which I downloaded now, this seems not to work. I mean it works but I can not see the old register values. How can I achieve that in this newest version? Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Options > Options > Debugging > Run trace`, then I suggest you use:

- Don't enter system DLLs
- Always trace over string commands
- Remember memory
- Synchronize CPU and run trace

For greater run trace speed, also go to `Options > Options > Debugging` and check:

- Allow fast command emulation

Reload you program (CTRL + F2), then:

- `Trace > Trace into` or `Trace > Trace over`

Once your program has finished (or if you have hit a condition in `Trace > Set condition`) go to `View > Run trace` and then you should see a grayed CPU register pane with registers value changing for each of the selected instruction.

If that doesn't work, close Ollydbg, delete the *.ini file in the OllyDbg folder, restart ollydbg and then redo the whole procedure.